# Delete Nodes Spritekit when interact

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a circle in the center of my view. Circles known as enemyBall come and collide with it. I want to detect these collisions and then remove the enemyBalls from the view.

func generateEnemyBall(){

```
    let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode()
    let randomColor = Int((arc4random_uniform(UInt32(circleTextures.count))))
    enemyBall.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: circleTextures[randomColor])
    enemyBall.size = CGSize(width: mainCircle.size.width / 5, height: mainCircle.size.width / 5)
    enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width / 2)
    enemyBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    let quadrant = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
    enemyBallForce = -CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(100)))

    switch quadrant {

    case 0:

        enemyBall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - 20, y: self.frame.maxY - 100)

        self.addChild(enemyBall)

        let dx = (enemyBall.position.x) - mainCircle.position.x
        let dy = (enemyBall.position.y) - mainCircle.position.y

        let impulse = applyImpulse(dx: dx, dy: dy)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: enemyBallForce * impulse.dx, dy: enemyBallForce * impulse.dy))

        break
```

Now what should i do.

Comment: Look in the Sprite-Kit documentation here on SO - there are some good examples of collision and contact detection using Sprite-Kit in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit newer to swift that's why I would like to answer your question using objective C.

In didMoveToView add:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

add few more properties to your enemyball i.e.

```
enemyball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballhitcategory;
enemyball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballhitcategory;
enemyball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballhitcategory;
```

where ballhitcategory could be any unsigned constant integer value.

Then in didBeginContact delegate method:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *body1,*body2;

    body1 = contact.bodyA;
    body2 = contact.bodyB;

    //Do your ball removal here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try both of the Solutions, and update you with the progress

Comment: Can you explain to me the last part inside the didBeginContact Function, of what body1 and body2 are?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the SKPhysicsContactDelegate

```
class GameScene: SKScene, **SKPhysicsContactDelegate** {
...
}
```

This delegate method gets called when there is contact:

```
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
...
}
```

Delete node

```
enemyBall.removeFromParent()
```

Comment: The code is working but only some enemy Balls get deleted not all of them

Answer (score 0):

Well after digging through. This is what worked best for me, as i was generating enemyBalls randomly.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()

}
```

Body B as i know was going to be the enemyBall, hence i accessed it's node and then removed it.
Simply using removed some of the nodes.

```
 enemyBall.removeFromParent()
```

Thankyou @DeepakRastogi and @JPAquino